Does this definition of a branch of a multiple-valued function contradicts the Example?
I was studying the book, "Complex Analysis" by John H Mathews and Russel W Howell. The definition of a branch of a multiple-valued function given was as folllws:

Let $w = f(z)$ be a multiple-valued function. A branch of $f$ is any single-valued function $f_0$ that is continuous in some domain and, at each point $z$ in the domain, assigns one of the values of $f(z).$

My understanding of this definition is that,
A function $f_0$ is said to be a branch of the multiple-valued function $f$ if $f_0$ is continuous on the domain $D_1\subseteq D,$ where $D$ is the domain of $f.$
However, this understanding of mine contradicts what's presented in an example that follows after this definition (, in the book). The example is:

Let us consider some branches of the two-valued square root
function $f(z) = z^{1/2}$. We define the principal square root function as
$$ f_1(z) = r^{1/2}\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} + i r^{1/2}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} = r^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2}, $$
where we require that $r > 0$ and $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$. The function $f_1$ is a branch of $f$.
We can find other branches of the square root function. For example, let
$$ f_2(z) = r^{1/2}\cos{\frac{\theta + 2\pi}{2}} + i r^{1/2}\sin{\frac{\theta + 2\pi}{2}} = r^{1/2}e^{i(\theta + 2\pi)/2}, $$
where $r > 0$ and $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$.
If we use the identities $\cos{\frac{\theta + 2\pi}{2}} = -\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}$ and $\sin{\frac{\theta + 2\pi}{2}} = -\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}$,
then we see that
$$ f_2(z) = -r^{1/2}\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} - i r^{1/2}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} = -r^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2} = -f_1(z), $$
so $f_1$ and $f_2$ can be thought of as "plus" and "minus" square root functions.
The negative real axis is called a branch cut for the functions $f_1$ and $f_2$. It is characterized by the fact that each point on
the branch cut is a point of discontinuity for both functions $f_1$ and $f_2$.

The last line says that,

It is characterized by the fact that each point on the branch cut is a point of discontinuity for both functions $f_1$ and $f_2$.

So, the branch $f_1$ and $f_2$ of $f$ are discontinuous on it's domain $\{(r,\theta):r>0\text{ and } -\pi\lt \theta \leq \pi\}$ for all the points $(r,\theta)$ satisfying $-\pi\lt \theta \lt 0.$
But this contradicts my understanding of a branch for it should've been continuous on the subdomain $\{(r,\theta):r>0\text{ and } -\pi\lt \theta \leq \pi\}$ of the domain of $f.$
Any help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.

(i) You're right, the stated definition and example are not compatible. (ii) Fixing the definition, unfortunately, requires a certain amount of care and/or mind-reading. (iii) A reasonable attempt is "...$f_0$ is continuous except possibly along a disjoint union of at most countably-many piecewise-smooth arcs, called branch cuts of $f_0$."

This is in fact misleading since the definition of a branch is imprecise. I do not have access to the book, but the following is unclear:

What is the domain of the (single-valued) function $f_0$? It could be  $D_1$ (case 1) or some open subset $D_0 \subset \mathbb C$ such that $D_0 \subset D$ (case 2). In the second case $f_0$ is required to be continuous on the open subset $D_1 \subset D_0$. In other words, in the second case a branch of $f$ is a triple $(f_0, D_0,D_1)$ consisting of open subsets $D_0, D_1 \subset \mathbb C$ with $D_1 \subset D_0$ and a function $f_0 : D_0 \to \mathbb C$ such that $f_0(z) \in f(z)$ for all $z \in D_0$ and $f_0 \mid_{D_1}$ is continuous.

In your example $f_1$ and $f_2$ are defined on $\mathbb C^* = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$, but they are discontinuous at all $z \in N = (-\infty,0)$. In the sense of case 1 they are therefore no branches of $f$.
However, the restrictions $g_i = f_i \mid_{\mathbb C^* \setminus N}$ are continuous on the domain $\mathbb C^* \setminus N$, hence the triples $(f_i,\mathbb C^* \setminus N, \mathbb C^*)$ are branches of $f$ in the sense of case 2. There is no continuous extension of $g_i$ to an open subset $D_0 \subset \mathbb C$ such that $\mathbb C^* \setminus N \subsetneqq D_0$.
